# Mutate, across, contains to sum

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I want to create a new column that sums up values from existing columns.

Consider iris dataset:

```r
iris1 <- iris %>% mutate(totalSepalLength = across(contains("Sepal"), sum))
```

This gives me a new column which is of type tibble. If I access `iris1$totalSepalLength`, it does not sum *row-wise* but rather, gives a total sum for the two columns:

```
# A tibble: 150 x 2
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
          <dbl>       <dbl>
 1         876.        459.
 2         876.        459.
 3         876.        459.
 4         876.        459.
 5         876.        459.
 6         876.        459.
 7         876.        459.
 8         876.        459.
 9         876.        459.
10         876.        459.
# ... with 140 more rows
```

I have tried multiple variations of across but I can't seem to get it work:

```r
> iris1 <- iris %>% mutate(totalSepalLength = sum(c_across(contains("Sepal"))))
> glimpse(iris1)
Rows: 150
Columns: 6
$ Sepal.Length     <dbl> 5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4, 4.6, 5.0, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.3, 5.8, 5.7, 5.4, 5.1, 5.7, 5.1, 5.4, 5.1, 4~
$ Sepal.Width      <dbl> 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3~
$ Petal.Length     <dbl> 1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.7, 1.5, 1~
$ Petal.Width      <dbl> 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0~
$ Species          <fct> setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa,~
$ totalSepalLength <dbl> 1335.1, 1335.1, 1335.1, 1335.1, 1335.1, 1335.1, 1335.1, 1335.1, 1335.1, 1335.1, 1335.1, 1335.1, 1335.1, 1335.1,~
>
```

I am specifically looking for a solution that uses dplyr (mutate→across) workflow.

Comment: Use `mutate(totalSepalLength = rowSums(across(contains("Sepal"))))`.

Comment: iris1 <- iris %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(totalSepalLength = sum(c_across(starts_with("Sepal"))))